# ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit HTMLEditor not displayed properly

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-ajax

I have used ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit HTMLEditor. The layout of the toolbars is not appropriately displayed. The toolbar which should be in 3 lines is comming in 9 lines

Answer (score 0):

you should try download latest AJAX Toolkit from [Codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/33804)

Comment: I already have the latest version. I have actually used it in a user control which is dynamically added to a asp page. Does it create any problems?

Comment: Yes and it depends, On which event you are adding contol to Page...?

Comment: try in on page render event and set it to disable false and then on button's click set it to true...because i guess when you click on button it loaded dynamically...but if you add it on pre render than its render along with page...try and let us know..

Comment: Actually im setting a flag in a session and using server.transfer() on same page and then in Page_init() im creating the control and adding it. Sorry for incorrect info earlier. Actually I feel it is a CSS related issue. As, when I see the user control (which has HTML editor) in design view in VS, the toolbars are displayed perfecctly in two lines.

Comment: well this may be because of width you have set of HTML Editor...and don't try add control on Page_init().. use on prerender event...

Comment: I did not set the width earlier now ive set it to 100% still the problem persists